# Set cache-control header in getInitialProps() in NextJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I need to set `Cache-Control` header with a dynamic value in `getInitialProps` method. I tried the below.

```
if(context.res){
    context.res.setHeader('Cache-Control','My-Cache-Control');
    context.res.setHeader('My-Header','My-Value');
}
```

But it looks looks like NextJs is overriding the header value before sending the response. Below is the `cache-control` header value in response header in browser.

```
Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate
My-Header: My-Value
```

Let me know if anything is missing.

Answer (score 4):

`Cache-Control` headers [are overridden in development](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/337fb6a9aadb61c916f0121c899e463819cd3f33/server/render.js#L181-L185), so that pages do not get cached by the browser.

It will work in production (`next build && next start`).

Answer (score 2):

as mentioned in this [github bug](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/1730)

use `res.setHeader()`

**res** is a Node.js http.ServerResponse

Comment: `res` is same as `context.res`.

Comment: if so you should reopen the bug in github i guess